# Get gRPC service metrics using java-grpc-prometheus

Tags: grpc, metrics, grpc-java

I am trying to get some metrics using the [java-grpc-prometheus](https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/java-grpc-prometheus) library.
I would like to get some metrics like below

gRPC sessions,
no of calls,
respective duration,
no of API calls been made towards internal apis,
timeouts,
interface resets

My question is we are using bi-directional Streaming API and I read that it is setup on a single TCP session which is reused by the clients. How do I know how many client sessions have been initiated?

Answer (score 1):

Get all root channels using [Channelz.GetTopChannels()](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/proto/grpc/channelz/channelz.proto#L426) which will give you all client sessions.

[A short introduction to Channelz](https://grpc.io/blog/a-short-introduction-to-channelz/)